# How to insert 100 headings at page load without a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First post on here, so bear with me! I'm supposed to insert 100 h3 headings on page load ("Accusation 1, Accusation 2, Accusation 3,...Accusation 100"). We're only using 1 loop for the entire lab, and that will be used with other code in the lab, so I'm trying to do this without using a loop, if possible.

**Also, the lab is supposed to teach about scope and hoisting, so we can't use "let" or "const", only "var".

```
var accusation = 1;

var createHeading = function () {
  var heading = $('<h3></h3>').text("Accusation " + accusation);
  $('body').append(heading);
  accusation++;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  createHeading();
  accusation++;
  console.log(accusation);
  if (accusation > 100) {
    return;
    console.log('reached 100');
  }

})
```

I'm wanting this function to repeat and increment without using a loop, but it's only producing the first h3 heading.

Comment: It's really unclear what the restrictions are on your program and why they exist at all. Do you think you could elaborate a little more?

Comment: _"the lab is supposed to teach about scope and hoisting, so we can't use "let" or "const", only "var""_  this too doesn't make any sense. For instance, `let` and `const` are quite excellent for teaching about block scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/)! Have the function call itself.

```js
var accusation = 1;

var createHeading = function() {
  var heading = $('<h3></h3>').text("Accusation " + accusation);
  $('body').append(heading);
  accusation++;

  if (accusation >= 100) {
    console.log("Reached 100;");
    return;
  } else {
    createHeading();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  createHeading();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and it's internal mapper callback to build an elements array and simply append that array

```js
var headings = Array.from({length:100}, (_,i) => $('<h3>', {text: `Accusation ${i+1}`}))

$('body').append(headings)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```